# Optimizing custom IDCT calculation

Tags: c++, image, optimization, jpeg

For an image format I have to decode a jpeg like compression. The steps are pretty standard, however the color coding and the produced IDCT values seem to be slightly different (I think, I am no expert). This is why using a standard JPEG library produced invalid results it seems and I had to implement it myself.

Now I am not really happy with the performance. After optimizing the naive approach by doing some caching of data that does not change I need ~150ms to decode a 1024x1024 image. Of that 120ms is spent in the idct function which looks like this:

```
float idctHelper(const int16_t *inBlock, int32_t u, int32_t v, int32_t blockWidth, int32_t blockHeight) {
    glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp> vec1{};
    glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp> vec2{};
    glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp> vec3{};

    float result = 0.0f;
    for (auto y = 0; y < blockHeight; ++y) {
        for (auto x = 0; x < blockWidth; x += 4) {
            const auto idx = (v * 8 + u) * 64 + y * 8 + x;
            vec1 = glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp>(inBlock[y * blockWidth + x], inBlock[y * blockWidth + x + 1], inBlock[y * blockWidth + x + 2], inBlock[y * blockWidth + x + 3]);
            vec2 = glm::vec<4, float, glm::packed_lowp>(idctLookup[idx], idctLookup[idx + 1], idctLookup[idx + 2], idctLookup[idx + 3]);
            vec3 = vec1 * vec2;
            result += vec3.x + vec3.y + vec3.z + vec3.w;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template<typename T, typename U = T>
U clamp(T value, T min, T max) {
    return static_cast<U>(std::min<T>(std::max<T>(value, min), max));
}

void idct(int16_t *outBlock, int16_t *inBlock, bool isLuminance, int32_t blockWidth = 8, int32_t blockHeight = 8) {
    for (auto y = 0; y < blockHeight; ++y) {
        for (auto x = 0; x < blockWidth; ++x) {
            auto value = static_cast<int16_t>(std::round(
                    0.25f * idctHelper(inBlock, x, y, blockWidth, blockHeight)));
            if (isLuminance) {
                value = clamp<int16_t>(static_cast<int16_t>(value + 128), 0, 255);
            } else {
                value = clamp<int16_t>(value, -256, 255);
            }

            outBlock[y * blockWidth + x] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have tried to use (potentially) SIMD and low precision operations to speed up the `idctHelper` but now I am kinda lost on where I can continue optimizing this. I would really appreciate any idea or hint.

Comment: Consider adding a bit more of the surrounding context code and asking over at Code Review. Generally when you have code that works that you'd like to work better, [Code Review is the place to ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking). And yes, I did mean to link to the How to Ask page. It's the best place to start if this is your first question.

Comment: Oh cool, I havent heard of that community before :)

Comment: Fast algorithms exist for DCT calculation. Difficult to understand your code, but I understand you implement a classic matrix multiplication, much less efficient

Comment: Twice I go to the same source today. In the JPEG source code at http://www.colosseumbuilders.com/sourcecode/index.html there is an optimized DCT. If I remember correctly, it shows the channels. If your have a good compiler it will optimize the channels. If you have a bad compiler, you have to manually remove the NoOP steps.